# Smart pointer and external code interaction via JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, smart-pointers, ns-3

I'm wondering what the best way is to have a pointer (via memory address) to an object in a C++ library which makes liberal use of smart pointers (ns-3). At the moment, I use path-based lookup and I'm concerned about its efficiency, since it seems to do full tree traversal for each call. If I maintain a standard pointer to the object for use across the JNI boundary, then the object may be disposed of while Java still holds a reference to it. Is the best idea to use a pointer to a smart pointer instead?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was basically our solution.  On the Java side, objects are held as simple ids, with a very simple algorithmic mapping of the id to a pointer (a `reinterpret_cast`, in fact).  For objects managed by reference counted pointers, the "object" pointed to by the id is a reference counted pointer.

And just in case: don't forget to free it in the finalizer.

Comment: Could you post an example Please!

Comment: We've since dropped support for Java, so I don't have the code handy, but from memory, we kept the object pointers in a Java long (which is `jlong` in C++); we'd initialize it to zero, insert the pointer with something like `*reinterpret_cast<void*>(&variable)`, and extract it with the opposite.  (This was based on what swig does; my colleague in implemented the Java interface was a maintainer of swig, and steered me in this direction.)